# OpsCenter 5.0.1 creates invalid cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, opscenter

When modifying the cluster configuration via OpsCenter Cassandra fails to restart due to the following error

```
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [multithreaded_compaction, memtable_flush_queue_size, preheat_kernel_page_cache, compaction_preheat_key_cache, in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb] from your cassandra.yaml
```

Removing the properties and manually restarting Cassandra fixes things but this shouldn't really be required.

Comment: what version of c* are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpsCenter support for 2.1 is coming in version 5.1, currently 2.1 is unsupported.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/opscenter/opscUpgrading_g.html

Eta for 5.1 is January per this post:
http://www.datastax.com/2014/12/announcing-datastax-enterprise-4-6-and-opscenter-5-1

Comment: and do you know when version 5.1 is expected to be released?

Comment: Updated post with expected eta.